# Can you dynamically resize Windows Command Line window?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

Windows Command Line window has a fixed size. You can change it, but not on-the-fly, with a mouse.

But maybe it's just me or my system (Windows 7).

**Can you dynamically resize Windows Command Line window?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As other users have pointed out: **it is impossible** with standard `cmd`. You can only adjust the window size via parameters.

I found an extension to `cmd` called **Console**.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/?source=navbar

You just install/extract it and make it visible in the `PATH`.
Console enables you to resize the window, set transparency, use tabs etc. etc. Very useful!

---

edit: a new project called *cmder* has emerged recently: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder

It looks VERY promissing!!

Comment: The above statement isn't completely true. You can resize with the mouse. But dragging from the corners, not the top and bottom. Although, width appears to be limited to the configured *width* property as a maximum.

Comment: What needs to be added to the PATH variable? Can this replace the cmd window?

Answer (score 12):

In windows 7 use the mode command.

```
mode con:cols=80 lines=40
```

Comment: Works even with Windows 10 PowerShell.

Comment: Great!, works on winxp too.

Comment: You lose the vertical scroll though, at least on Win7

Comment: @golimar, you can leave off the lines=40 (or change the number to something larger) to just change the number of columns.  You still loose the previous buffer/history, however.

Answer (score 9):

This is done via the `Properties > Layout tab` of the window or the shortcut.

[image]

Detailed instructions - [How to Make the Windows Command Prompt Wider](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19982/how-to-make-the-windows-command-prompt-wider/)

Comment: this i know, this is not dynamic. I'd like it to behave like a terminal on linux

Comment: If you set it to a large size, can't you re-size it smaller as you wish?

Answer (score 5):

You can change the screen buffer size in the Layout tab of the Preferences dialog (click on the icon in the top left corner of the window to get to the menu). Making the screen buffer bigger will allow you to then change the window size.

If you do this though, the text will extend past the window and you will have to scroll to see it. There is no way to dynamically change the screen buffer size like you want AFAIK.

Answer (score 4):

via https://stackoverflow.com/a/35302566/923560 :

A simple command to fix the window size that I use all the time:

```
wmic
```

It will open the Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line and remove the size limits.
Then just close it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 command prompt has that now.
The buffer size automatically grows and shrinks when you use the resize arrows.

Reference:

https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/

Comment: I'm so excited! Real mouse resizing, line-based selection, shift-key selection, real word wrapping that doesn't insert line breaks into your selection when you copy... wow. It's finally happened. And it only took ~25 yrs. Now if my company would only update our systems to Windows 10...

Answer (score 0):

You can also increase the command prompt window size through command lines

```
ex:mode 250
```

In the place of 250 add any value of your wish.

Comment: Can you confirm this works. I have just tested it with no result.